# armadillo inverse problem in C++ (windows,Visual Stdio 2017)

Tags: c++

I want to use armadillo C++ in Visual Stdio of Windows platform, but after I configure the armadillo environment in Visual Stdio, everything is right until I use the matrix inverse function. Visual Stdio reports errors like "error: inv(): use of ATLAS or LAPACK must be enabled". I don't know what's going on and how to fix it so that I can use the inv() or matrix.i() function. Any help will be welcomed, please.

I use C++ to write my code, and the environment is Visual Stdio 2017 in Windows, the armadillo-9.600.5.  I have

1. added the three libs "blas.lib，libf2c.lib，lapack.lib" to the additional dependencies of Visual Stdio.
2. added the including dirtionary of armadillo to the VC++ -> include path of Visual Stdio.
3. commented the following code in \Armadillo\include\armadillo_bits\config.hpp to use lapack and blas

#define ARMA_USE_LAPACK

#define ARMA_USE_BLAS

But it still reports "std::logic_error" in debug.hpp, and "error: inv(): use of ATLAS or LAPACK must be enabled" in command line.

Comment: Have you searched the header files for that message?

Comment: Instead of commenting out `#define ARMA_USE_LAPACK`, make sure these lines are uncommented (not commented). In other words, make sure there is no `//` or `/*` in front of `#define ARMA_USE_LAPACK` etc

Comment: Could you tell me how to search header files for the message ?

Comment: And I did tried to comment out this line---"#define ARMA_USE_LAPACK" .  Then VS reported many errors like "Mat cannot be specified". So I withdraw doing it.  I am kind of confused by this

Comment: @cmm No, make sure the line is NOT commented out. If you are still getting errors, you should download Armadillo again. Use it without modifying any of its source files.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I realized several errors in my configration. I did comment the code "#define ARMA_USE_LAPACK"  which I need to comment it out. And I use 64 bit libs in Visual Stdio, so VS cannot check the existence of those libs because the programs are supposed to use 32bit libs. Then I commented out the lines in source codes and downloaded 32bit libs to replace the 64bit ones. Finally, it works !   And Thank you very much for your help !